# Can not send Codename One IOS Build to the Build Server

Tags: codenameone

I have an issue when trying to send my IOS debug build to the build server.

It is giving me the following message:

A certificate from Apple with the appropriate password is required for building an iOS native app!

Looks like this happened only after I generated my Android debug and release keystrokes. Now Android build sending works fine but IOS build fails while I try to send it to the server and giving me this error on my Netbeans console!!!

The build was working fine before and my certificates and provisioning profiles are still valid and exist on my filesystem with the right path as maintained in my CN1 project properties.

The error message points to my build.xml file line 91:

```
<target name="build-for-ios-device" depends="clean,copy-ios-override,copy-libs,jar,clean-override">
    <codeNameOne 
        jarFile="${dist.jar}"
        displayName="${codename1.displayName}"
        packageName = "${codename1.packageName}"
        mainClassName = "${codename1.mainName}"
        version="${codename1.version}"
        icon="${codename1.icon}"
        vendor="${codename1.vendor}"
        subtitle="${codename1.secondaryTitle}"

        targetType="iphone"
        certificate="${codename1.ios.debug.certificate}"
        certPassword="${codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword}"
        provisioningProfile="${codename1.ios.debug.provision}"
        appid="${codename1.ios.appid}"
        automated="${automated}"
        />                          //This is line 91
</target>
```

Please help me to fix the build issue.

Answer (score 0):

That means the file for the certificate or provisioning was moved, removed or became inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shai and you are right my path to certificates changed so i changed it back so thanks a lot